# Python function to create a dictionary and run operations on it as given below

Tags: python-3.x

Write a python function which generates the list of n dictionaries representing n students. Each dictionary should have two keys Name and Marks, the value of Marks key should be a list of 10 elements representing marks in 10 subjects as [a1,a2,a3,a4,...,a10].

Create another function which accepts such dictionary and performs operation on marks and returns a list as [α1,α2,α3,α4,...,α10]
where
`αi = βαi − 1 + (1−β)ai` and `β = 0.99, α0=1, i=1,2,3,...,10`

Example of Dictionary

```py
{{'Marks': [80, 60, 57, 84, 52, 98, 49, 58, 73, 65], 'Name': 'Rahul'},
 {'Marks': [58, 66, 50, 94, 87, 98, 82, 62, 83, 67], 'Name': 'Deepak'}}
```

```
def create_dict(n):
    dicts=[]
    for i in range(n):
        school={}
        school["Name"]=name[i]       # user an input name and marks dictionaries
        school["Marks"]=marks[i]    # the value of n will change as per list.
        dicts.append(school)
    return dicts
```

```
def alpha_i(a, n):      # Functn to calculate alpha i
    alpha = []
    beta = 0.99
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i)
        alpha.append((beta * alpha[i-1]) + (1 - beta) * a[i])
    return alpha
```

```
def marks_operation(smpl_dict):            # functn to perform op on dictionary
    marks = smpl_dict['Marks']
    return alpha_i(marks, len(marks))
```

Comment: Please, can you provide any code of yours which doesn't work. It would be easier to work from that.

Comment: i have added the code which i wrote . but somewhere i m getting lost